# How to install PostgreSQL Anonymizer 0.8.1 on Amazon RDS?

Tags: postgresql

Since version 0.9 of PostgreSQL Anonymizer, you [can't install](https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/INSTALL.html#install-in-the-cloud) it on Amazon RDS anymore since the extension anon is not added to Amazon RDS yet (by Amazon). For the time being we could install version 0.8.1 of PostgreSQL Anonymizer. This question is to get answered how to perform that installation which I'm going to try and document myself.

https://gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer/-/blob/24b1d46250ea6adb342a066d41bc2e8afb893cb7/docs/INSTALL.md#install-in-the-cloud

Related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69295102/1385429

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is described mostly already [here](https://gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer/-/issues/161). I'll add it here as well to make it a bit easier to find and understand.

```sql
## clone the repo en cd into it
git clone https://gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer.git
cd ./postgresql_anonymizer

## Checkout the version that allows standalone installation
git checkout 0.8.1

## Create the anon_standalone.sql file
make standalone

## Execute that sql file against your Amazon RDS instance
psql -h <host> -U <username> -d <database-name> -a -f anon_standalone.sql
```